# discord.py AttributeError when creating text channel

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.10

I'm trying to make a discord bot for my server, and create a channel for modmail. But every time I try creating one, this error appears.
I'm using python 3.10

```
  File "C:\Users\dyimi\Desktop\Code related stuff\python\discord..py\Palace Guard\cogs\modmail.py", line 35, in on_message  
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=text_channel_name, overwrites=overwrites)
  File "C:\Users\dyimi\Desktop\Code related stuff\python\discord..py\Palace Guard\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", 
line 948, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
  File "C:\Users\dyimi\Desktop\Code related stuff\python\discord..py\Palace Guard\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", 
line 844, in _create_channel
    'id': target.id
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Here's my code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.lower() in ["yes", "y", "ya", "yee", "ye", "no", "n", "nope"]:
            return
        
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        
        def check(msg):
            return msg.content.lower() in ["yes", "y", "ya", "yee", "ye"] and msg.author == message.author
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
            await message.channel.send("Create ticket to modmail in Veemo's Kingdom? Yes or no.")
            response = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        if response:
            guild = discord.utils.get(self.client.guilds, id=834666434042658816)
            text_channel_name = message.author.name + "-" + message.author.discriminator
            roles = guild.roles
            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)
            }
            for role in roles:
                if role.name not in mod_roles_list:
                    overwrites[role.name] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=text_channel_name, overwrites=overwrites)
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Ticket not created.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is with the `overwrites` dictionary variable,

Below line appends the `overwrites` variable with `keys` as `str` instead of `discord.py Role` objects. Which causes this `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'` error.

```
overwrites[role.name] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)
```

**Output with issue**:

```
{
  <Role id=<id no> name='@everyone'>: <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>,
  '@everyone': <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>,
  'Bot': <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>,
  'pbot': <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>
}
```

It should be like below, so the `key` is `discord.py Role` object which contains the attribute `id`.

```
overwrites[role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False)
```

**Output**:

```
{
  <Role id=<id no> name='@everyone'>: <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>,
  <Role id=<id no> name='Bot'>: <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>,
  <Role id=<id no> name='pbot'>: <discord.permissions.PermissionOverwrite object at ...>
}
```

Comment: A bit overcomplicated (you could just say that discord.py expects a Role / User / Member as the key) but the fix is correct so +1.